# What does the term 'metadata' mean?

Tags: notepad++

I'm using notepad++ and the term 'Metadata' is bugging me in my html code. Does someone know what it means? To clarify: I need to know the uses of it and where it should go. If you could send a screenshot, that would be awesome.

Regards, Science.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+metadata+in+html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metadata is data about data, so for example on a normal file this can be creation date, last modified date, user that owns the file. In case of HTML it says something about the html document. 
The metadata is used by web browsers and search engines to know more about the page they are visiting. This could be the language, description, author keywords for search engines.

You can find more information about HTML metadata here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

So it is not necessary when creating an HTML document, but it would be useful if you put the HTML page online.

Comment: Thanks. It's just I'm new to HTML coding.